# Building Regex Expression

Tags: regex

Can you tell me the regex for capturing class name from below line:

```
[2011-09-14 20:43:31:943 GMT][E08C17F94E8.http-8080-Processor21]com.abc.MyClass] INFO login successful
```

Here, I need to capture `MyClass`.

So far, I was able to capture entire `com.abc.MyClass` using `(?i)^(?:[^\[]*\[){3}`

But I couldn't capture `MyClass`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The best regex to do this is `/(MyClass)/`. If you need something more generic, try to be more generic.

Comment: `.+abc\.([\w]+).*` would work... more details?

Comment: I cannot hardcode any class name as it could be any name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume there are never brackets after that last one, it is pretty simple:

```
(\w+)\][^]]$
```

This captures all of the alphanumeric characters directly preceding the last `]` in the string.

Note: you don't need to do `[^\]]` because the spec for PCRE says if the `]` is the first in the character list, you don't need to escape it.

**EDIT:** Since you cannot assume no brackets, here is another one that will work:

```
\[.+?\]\[.+?\].*?(\w+)\]
```

This throws away the first two sets of brackets, and grabs the largest chunk of alphanumeric characters before the next bracket. The `?` in `.+?` makes it a non-greedy multiplier, so it will match *as few characters as possible*, which makes this regex very simple and efficient.

Nothing against daxnitro, but that regex makes me want to give up programming.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about [^\]].  Makes it a little less gross, but yours does still look cleaner.  :-/

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible for the end (the part that says "login successful") to have brackets, you can use this:

```
^\[[^]]*\]\[[^]]*\][^]]*\.([^]]+)\].*$
```

Let's see if I can break this down a little...

`^\[[^]]*\]` matches the first bracket, all following non-"]" characters, and a closing bracket.  This is the `[2011-09-14 20:43:31:943 GMT]` part.

`\[[^]]*\]` then matches an opening bracket, all following non-"]" characters, and another closing bracket.  This is the `[E08C17F94E8.http-8080-Processor21]` part.

`[^]]*\.([^]]+)` then matches all non-"]" characters, followed by a period, followed by one or more non-"]" characters.  This is the `com.abc.MyClass` part.  The `MyClass` part gets matched to the part in parenthesis.

`\].*$` matches a closing bracket and the rest of the string.  This is the `] INFO login successful` part.

So if you replace `^\[[^]]*\]\[[^]]*\][^]]*\.([^]]+)\].*$` with `$1` in your example, you're left with `MyClass`.

Comment: The text could be anything, not just "login successful".. Also, MyClass could be any class since its a log file...Will this work?

Comment: It should. Works when I test it. You might want to add the ^ and $ markers to it though... (I'm gonna edit that in now)